# How to use an explicit cursor to sort through table information

Tags: sql, oracle, testing, plsql, procedure

I'm trying to create a procedure which returns the names of people who have had a test result of 1, but currently have a status of 0. I've broken up how I would accomplish this into essentially three steps: check the people table for everyone whose current status is 0, use an explicit cursor with the pids of those people to go through the people_testresult table which stores the test result information, and then see if any of the pids has taken a test and gotten a result of 1 before.

I've done (or at least tried to) the first two steps, but I'm getting an error for the select statement of my cursor (screenshot at the bottom). I'm also confused about how exactly I would use my explicit cursor to go through all the test result data, especially because every person takes multiple tests. How would you get it to print a name only once, and to only count when the test result is 1 if the test was taken before they had a status of 0?

Here's my work so far:

```
set serveroutput on;
create or replace procedure get_Recovered
is
current_zero int;

cursor c1 is
  select pid from people p, people_testresult ptr where p.pid = ptr.pid and p.status = 0;
v_pid people.pid%type;

begin
  -- check people table for current 0 status
  select count(*) into current_zero from people p where status = 0;
  if current_zero = 0 then
    dbms_output.put_line('No person with a current status of 0 found');
  -- save pids to explicit cursor to check with test results
  else
    open c1;
    loop
      fetch c1 into current_zero;
      exit when c1%notfound;
      dbms_output.put_line('ID: ' || v_pid);
      dbms_output.put_line(current_zero);
      -- see if pid has positive test result in past (date before)
      --- of the multiple tests a person/pid takes, one with past date before status = 0 has tresult = 1
      dbms_output.put_line(pname ' has tested 1 before but has current status 0');
    end loop;
    close c1;
  end if;
end;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Without any sample data, I have difficulties in understanding what exactly you want. However, see if such a modified code helps.

Error you got (column ambiguously defined) is related to cursor's `SELECT` statement. As both tables contain the `pid` column, Oracle doesn't know which one to use - prepend its name with a table name (or its alias).

I also defined a cursor variable (c1r c1%rowtype) which is capable of holding the whole row returned by a cursor (so that you wouldn't have to declare all variables separately). My cursor returns some more info than yours: `pname` (you used in `dbms_output.put_line`) and `result` (so that you could check whether its value is `1` or not).

This code probably won't do what you wanted, but - it should compile, at least (if tables contain names I used). Feel free to improve it.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_Recovered
IS
   current_zero  INT;

   CURSOR c1 IS
      SELECT p.pid, p.pname, ptr.result
        FROM people p, people_testresult ptr
       WHERE     p.pid = ptr.pid
             AND p.status = 0;

   c1r           c1%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
   -- check people table for current 0 status
   SELECT COUNT (*)
     INTO current_zero
     FROM people p
    WHERE status = 0;

   IF current_zero = 0
   THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('No person with a current status of 0 found');
   ELSE
      -- save pids to explicit cursor to check with test results
      OPEN c1;

      LOOP
         FETCH c1 INTO c1r;

         EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;

         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('ID: ' || c1r.pid);

         -- see if pid has positive test result in past (date before)
         -- of the multiple tests a person/pid takes, one with past date before status = 0 has tresult = 1
         IF c1r.result = 1
         THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
               c1r.pname || ' has tested 1 before but has current status 0');
         END IF;
      END LOOP;

      CLOSE c1;
   END IF;
END;
```